# Does there exist a way to find the sum of the digits of the result from a large cubic root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The problem is as follows:

Find the sum of the digits of $B$:

$B=\sqrt[3]{1224 \times 1225\times 1226+35\sqrt[3]{34\times35\times36+35}}$

The possible answers given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&10\\
2.&18\\
3.&9\\
4.&12\\
\end{array}$

I've been tempted to use a calculator but this problem is **meant to be solved by hand**.

Does there exist a trick or anything for doing this, other than going by the brute force method of doing all the operations one by one?. **How can this be simplified or solved quickly?**. Can someone help me here?.

Comment: Hint: $(a-1)a(a+1) + a = a^3$. Apply it twice.

Comment: As Catalin says, recall $(n-1)(n+1) = n^2 - 1.$ Multiply by an extra $n,$ we get $(n-1)n(n+1) = n^3 - n.$ Here $n$ is the middle of three numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose you could just do it by hand, but that would be a pain in the butt. Thus, to flesh out Catalin Zara's hint:

Let $a=1225, b=35$. Then

$$B = \sqrt[3]{(a-1)(a)(a+1) + b\sqrt[3]{(b-1)(b)(b+1) + b}}$$

Noting that $(x-1)(x)(x+1) = (x^2 - 1)(x) = x^3 - x$, then the innermost radicand is equal to $b^3$ -- just move the $x$ over in the previous equation. Then that simplifies to $b$ and thus

$$B = \sqrt[3]{(a-1)(a)(a+1) + b^2}$$

*A priori*, it doesn't seem like we can apply it again. However, would it not be convenient for us if $b^2 = a$, to reapply the same trick? Indeed, if you happen to have $35^2$ memorized, or calculate it by hand, you'll find $b^2 = a$. Then the radicand simplifies to $a^3$ and then $B=a$.

Thus, $B=1225$, and finding the sum of the digits is trivial.